# Hundreds of emails in MailTo - Outlook/Windows?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Basically I have a table in my database of contacts. It has an email address assigned to each user.

I'm trying to create a button which, when clicked, does a mailto in the Bcc field of a new email, populated from the entire table's entries:

```
mailto:?bcc=<?php 
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 
    echo $rows['EMAIL']; 
    echo ", "; 
  } 
  mysql_close(); ?>
```

It works great on Firefox/MacMail on my Mac, but when I try with Internet Explorer/Outlook on Windows nothing happens (i.e. I click the button but it doesn't open a new Outlook message).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Internet Explorer (maximum of 2,083 characters, see [KB208427](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)) and Outlook (similar number of characters, I can't find an authoritative reference) have maximum URL lengths they can process. If you have hundreds of email addresses, you'll easily reach these limits.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code, the list of emailadresses always ends with an extra `,`.
I would get rid of that.

Also I suggest you do all the work in the database, rewrite the code to something like:

```
<?php
$param = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['param']);
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) as emailadresses 
          FROM email WHERE afield = '$param' ";
?>

mailto:?bcc=
<?php 
  $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result));
  echo $rows['EMAIL']; //no while loop needed, group_concat does all the work.
  mysql_close(); 
?>
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat